# localization in german language is not working properly,showing english text by default

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, localization, internationalization

I have done localization of iPhone project in english,german and french language.French and english are working fine with change of language on iPhone/simulator but german language is not working properly.

I have changed texts in the xib file for each language under the localization.
Whenever i am trying to change language to german(Belgium),XIB file with english text is getting shown on the simulator/iphone.

I have tried changing region first(belgium) and then language(German) but have no luck with it.
Please help me for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the identifier of your language (ie the name of the german `.lproj` folder)

Comment: The localization should not be named "German" and "Englisch". You need to name it "de" and "en". After clearning all targets and running in Simulator the right language xib will displayed.